# Low rep user accessing own deleted comments

Tags: support, comments

I could swear that I commented yesterday on [Where can I download Safari for Windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68836/where-can-i-download-safari-for-windows/94010#94010), but I am not seeing it now.

Assuming it has been deleted, is there anywhere to access it, and/or see the reason for it's deletion?

Comment: There is no way to see deleted comments. Only mods have that power.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a moderator removed the comment because it wasn't related to any question or answer particularly and was rather discussion about who might have downvoted an answer.  No-one, not even moderators, can see who voted for who (unless there is a pattern of vote abuse that is picked up by the system and alerted to us) and questioning a user on their voting isn't considered appropriate.

Unlike for questions, reasons are not stored for edits and deletion of comments so there is nothing to see.  As mentioned by @Mat, only moderators can see deleted comments.

Comment: Seems the intent of my comment was mistaken. I wanted to suggest that why ?they? downvoted the answer (If indeed was them, otherwise I would have then expected both our comments to be deleted) was stated, because I thought they may be suggesting that the date in the answer was wrong, but given the limited wording I wasn't sure.

Comment: Also, before I write up a "Please consider (at least) giving authors access to their deleted comments" meta question, if for no other reason that people could go crazy wondering if their crazy ;) (But it is also nice to have something to show for sometimes some time typing, i.m.o) has it already been suggested?

Comment: I don't know if it has been suggested, but if you do make a question I would so it on SO, not AD, as it's a site wide request that isn't particularly AD specific.  I can't comment on the thinking of the particular Mod who removed it, but even if the user *hadn't* downvoted, it's not fair to put other users on the spot - voting is totally anonymous by design - so it seemed a reasonable action to take.  Hope you understand our thinking.

Comment: PS, you are welcome to add the comment back in, but word it differently and make it anonymous, not specific to a particular user.  You could ask the question of if the comment is accurate or misguided without needing to tie that to a vote.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10589/discussion-between-stuffe-and-user66001)

Comment: FYI, users being able to see their deleted contents was requested and declined: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187279/let-us-view-our-deleted-comments